# Applying :focus CSS to input-field in shadowDOM and :focus CSS to shadow host

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, custom-element

I'm currently working on a custom element which is basically a slightly augmented version of an input element, hosting all of its building blocks (including an input element) in a shadow DOM.

When the internal input element has focus, the host element should be styled with a colored outline and box-shadow, as seen below:

[image]

Therefore the focus and blur event handlers of the input toggle an attribute "focussed" on the host element with the encapsulated styles looking like this:

```
:host([focussed]) {
    transition: outline 0.3s ease-in-out;
    outline-color: var(--focus-color, var(--default-focus-color)) !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px var(--focus-color, var(--default-focus-color)) !important;
}
```

**What I don't like about this approach:**

Exposing a custom attribute on the host that needs to be observed, in order to ensure the correctness of the visually represented state (e.g. consumer calls `setAttribute('focussed', '')`)

**Alternatives I considered:**

Of course my first thought was to encapsulate the attribute within the shadow DOM (or even toggle a class) on a container element filling out the space of the host element, but the problem is that overflowing contents such as outline and box-shadow seem to be forcefully hidden by the host element - which seems kind of logical.

I could dictate a fixed padding on the host element to ensure the visibility of the outline and shadow, but this would require considering different browser rendering behaviour of box-shadow and would feel counter-intuitive for custom styling by the consumer.

I'm looking for a best practice approach here and I would very much appreciate your educated thoughts on this one.

Comment: Could you include your custom element in a snippet so we can think on a solution with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open',
      delegatesFocus: true
    })
```

works in Chrome, Edge, Opera, not the others (yet)

This styles the input (in shadowDOM) itself with:

```css
:focus {
  transition: outline 1s ease-in-out;
  outline: 2px solid var(--focus-color,blue);
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px var(--focus-shadow-color,red);
}
```

**And** styles the **host** element with (global) CSS:

```css
  :focus {
    outline: 5px solid green;
  }
```

Full explanation and playground JSFiddle
*use Chrome/Edge/Opera first, then see lacking behaviour in others*:
https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/Lpqyg201/

It has some pointers for click/focus/blur workarounds.

For FireFox , Safari support I would **add** something not too fancy that can easily be removed.

For now it is unclear to me what the time frame at Mozilla and Apple is,
maybe Supersharp knows

Comment: This is just great! Thanks for the hint. Also, I found the reason why my host element cut off its shadow content as if it was set to `overflow: hidden`: I had set it to `contain: content` earlier. Yes, I will go shame walk myself through King's Landing now. Cheers.

Comment: Shame walk? That's no fun.. I always drown my sorrows in an extra beer here in Amsterdam. Cheers!

Comment: I've stopped to wait for Firefox and Safari about Web Components implementations ;-|